# Get existing search result in Magento block

Tags: php, magento

Gonna try to keep this short because it's pretty simple.

On the search results page there is clearly a collection of products that make up the search results.

I have my own module with its own blocks, I want to fetch this collection in my own block. I'd rather not use the catalogsearch helper to fetch the search string and perform another search because hitting the db twice for one search seems kind of excessive.

So, how do I find this collection? I've been poking around the source and trying to Google it but haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the easiest way to do this that I found was to use the `catalogsearch`helper's `getQuery` method:

```
$query = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery();
$items = $query->getResultCollection();
```

From a quick reading of the source I get the impression it shouldn't be doing a second search but I haven't checked too closely.